# C++ Class inside Structure and two callings at the same time

Tags: c++, class, struct, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

Looking a c++ code somewhere in the net, I noticed a piece of code like this

```
 opts.addOptions()(cOSS.str(), m_list, XYentry());
```

I really impressed of how this code is implemented and of course I wondered how it works.

So I tried to replicate this type of calling :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"


using namespace std;

class mypair {
public:

    int x;
    int y;

    mypair() {

        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    void operator()(int x1, int y1) {
        x = x1; 
        y = y1;
        cout << "x=" << x << "  y=" << y << endl;
    }

};



struct myrot {
    int     left;
    int     right;
    int     result;
    mypair  g;

    mypair  addOptions() {

        g.x = 3;
        g.y = 3;
        cout << "g.x=" << g.x << endl;
        cout << "g.y=" << g.y << endl;
        return g; 
    };

    void print_mypair() {

        cout << "g.x=" << g.x << endl;
        cout << "g.y=" << g.y << endl;

    }

    void operator()(int y) { result = y; }
    void operator() (void) {
        cout << "g.x=" << g.x << endl;
        cout << "g.y=" << g.y << endl;

    }


};

int main()
{


    myrot    t1;
    mypair  res;

    t1.left = 2;
    t1.right = 5;

    t1.addOptions()(5,5);
    t1.print_mypair();
    cout << "t1.g.x=" << t1.g.x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The calling `t1.addOptions()(5,5);` seems almost identical at least at the syntax level. So my questions are :

1) Does have a name this type of calling ?
2) How it really works ? If I remove the return type in the member function *addOptions* then I get error. Also if `t1.addOptions()(5,5);` will be changed to `res = t1.addOptions()(5,5);` where *res* is declared as *mypair* then I get also an error. The `void operator()(int x1, int y1)`  is called after the *addOption* but at the end g.x and g.y are both have the value 3 instead of the value 5.

So, can someone explain me what really happens here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement

```
t1.addOptions()(5,5);
```

basically works like this:

```
{
    mypair temp_variable = t1.add_options();
    temp_variable(5, 5);
}
```

Note that since `myrot::addOptions` returns the `mypair` object *by value*, the `mypair::operator()` function is called on a *copy* of the `myrot::g` member variable. If you want to modify the `myrot::g` variable you must return *by reference*:

```
mypair& addOptions() { ... }
```

Then the equivalent code becomes

```
{
    mypair& temp_variable = t1.add_options();
    temp_variable(5, 5);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks ! that is clarifying a little bit the code above. So what are the advantages of using such a complex-mystifying code ? Does this have a name ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not sure if I understand your answer.... you are just saying that there is no tech name of this technique and that is a clever way to do the job right ? I really i did not understand what are you trying to say with "And it won't pass code review in my team"

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove the return type in the member function addOptions then I get error.

If you change your addOptions return type to void, nothing will be returned and you will get the error because there will be nothing to call the operator() on.

> Also if t1.addOptions()(5,5); will be changed to res = t1.addOptions()(5,5); where res is declared as mypair then I get also an error.

Here it is in the other way. You declared the ()-operator to return void. So there is nothing to be saved in res.

This is just a concatenation of methods.

By the way, your class names should beginn with  capital letters. And your parameters in addOption should be declared as x and y and your class members either _x and _y or what I prefer:

```
void operator()(int x, int y) {
    this->x = x; 
    this->y = y;
    cout << "x=" << x << "  y=" << y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maik, with both examples (yours and "Some programmer dude") are all now clear to me !